# Run on remote machine results in error DEP0700

Tags: windows-iot

```
DEP0700 : Registration of the app failed. Windows cannot install package 
bada339c-667b-4f43-b692-5f73cc71d1d8 because the package requires architecture x86, 
but this computer has architecture ARM. (0x80073d10)
```

I have a windows 10 with vs2015 community loaded with addons and configuration as followed via various tutorials. Including enabling the "Developers Mode".

I am trying to run my Hello World app on my Raspberry Pi model B with Win10 IoT successfully installed. It is connected to my network via DHCP and shows in my Windows IoT core watcher app on my PC.

---

I can run the application locally, however, the error occurs when I try to run it on the remove machine.

---

I have tried changing the platform target to Any CPU as well as just ARM.

---

My windows 10 is fully checked for updates and installed. My Raspberry Pi was loaded with Windows 10 IoT 3 weeks ago.

[Here is the tutorial I am following](https://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/win10/samples/HelloWorld.htm)

Comment: OK, well it sounds like you building the binary for x86, as the error message says. Just double check that `release` is set for `Arm`

Comment: It turns out I missed an important step in that guide. You comment gave me the clue to finding that. TY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### In Summary

The problem is that ARM must be selected in the solution platforms dropdown list when wishing to run on a remote machine. The same for if you want to run the application on a windows desktop locally that the solution platforms dropdown list be set to x86 or x64.

### Checklist

1. Ensure the remote machine is identified and setup in the project properties.
   [image]
2. When you want to run on the remove machine, change the solution platform to ARM. Notice that local machine is missing from the list. You can now select Remote Machine.
   [image]
3. When you want to run the application locally as needed during development, change the solution platform to x86 or x64 depending on your Visual Studio install. Notice that local machine is now present in the list. You can now select Local Machine.
   [image]